# How to use GPU in my remote Ubuntu16.0 system for my model?

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, gpu, ubuntu-16.04

I am currently a training an RL program on my remote system(Ubuntu 16.04 10 GPU : RTX 2080 TI 11 GB, 512 GB ram, 36 CPU core). I noticed that the training is happening very slowly; it is supposed to be done in 7 hrs whereas the mine has been running for 12 hrs and is not even 1/3rd complete. I realized that my process is using the CPU instead of GPU.

How do I make sure that my program uses the GPU and not the CPU?

Comment: By RL, do you mean reinforcement learning?  If so, what software are you using to run your model?

Answer (score 0):

Which framework are you using to train the model? Make sure that you've installed the correct version of Cuda and CuDNN required by your specific framework and version.